# Create the evolution of exposure from inception and maturity of a list of loans in Python/Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, time-series

I have a DataFrame with a list of loans, with inception date, maturity, amount.
I would like to create a DataFrame with the evolution of the exposure as follows:

from:

| contract | amount | inception | maturity |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 100 | 31/12/2022 | 31/12/2042 |
| 2 | 90 | 31/12/2023 | 31/12/2052 |
| 3 | 50 | 31/12/2024 | 31/12/2035 |

to:

| date | 1 | 2 | 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 31/12/2022 | 100 | 0 | 0 |
| 31/12/2023 | 100 | 90 | 0 |
| 31/12/2024 | 100 | 90 | 50 |
| 31/12/2025 | 100 | 90 | 50 |
| ... | 100 | 90 | 50 |
| 31/12/2042 | 0 | 90 | 0 |
| ... | 0 | 90 | 0 |
| 31/12/2052 | 0 | 0 | 0 |

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First convert to datetimes by [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html), then subtract years and repeat rows by [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) with [`Index.repeat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.repeat.html), create counter column by [`GroupBy.cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) and add to years, last pivoting by [`DataFrame.pivot_table`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table.html) with `aggfunc='sum'` for aggregate sum if duplicated values:

```
df['inception'] = pd.to_datetime(df['inception'])
df['maturity'] = pd.to_datetime(df['maturity'])

df = (df.loc[df.index.repeat(df['maturity'].dt.year.sub(df['inception'].dt.year) + 1)]
        .assign(y = lambda x: x.groupby(level=0).cumcount().add(x['inception'].dt.year))
        .pivot_table(index='y',
                     columns='contract', 
                     values='amount', 
                     fill_value=0, 
                     aggfunc='sum')
        .rename(lambda x: f'31/12/{x}'))
```

---

```
print (df)
contract      1   2   3
y                      
31/12/2022  100   0   0
31/12/2023  100  90   0
31/12/2024  100  90  50
31/12/2025  100  90  50
31/12/2026  100  90  50
31/12/2027  100  90  50
31/12/2028  100  90  50
31/12/2029  100  90  50
31/12/2030  100  90  50
31/12/2031  100  90  50
31/12/2032  100  90  50
31/12/2033  100  90  50
31/12/2034  100  90  50
31/12/2035  100  90  50
31/12/2036  100  90   0
31/12/2037  100  90   0
31/12/2038  100  90   0
31/12/2039  100  90   0
31/12/2040  100  90   0
31/12/2041  100  90   0
31/12/2042  100  90   0
31/12/2043    0  90   0
31/12/2044    0  90   0
31/12/2045    0  90   0
31/12/2046    0  90   0
31/12/2047    0  90   0
31/12/2048    0  90   0
31/12/2049    0  90   0
31/12/2050    0  90   0
31/12/2051    0  90   0
31/12/2052    0  90   0
```

EDIT: You can subtract each 5 values per `amount` if `True`s in `is_instalment` by subtract column by multiplied counter by `5`:

```
print (df)
   contract  amount   inception    maturity  is_instalment
0         1     100  31/12/2022  31/12/2042           True
1         2      90  31/12/2023  31/12/2052          False
2         3      50  31/12/2024  31/12/2035          False


df['inception'] = pd.to_datetime(df['inception'])
df['maturity'] = pd.to_datetime(df['maturity'])

df['y'] = df['inception'].dt.year

df1 = df.loc[df.index.repeat(df['maturity'].dt.year.sub(df['y']) + 1)].copy()

df1['counter'] = df1.groupby(level=0).cumcount()
df1['Date'] = df1['y'].add(df1['counter'])

df1['amount'] = df1['amount'].mask(df1['is_instalment'], 
                                   df1['amount'].sub(df1['counter'].mul(5)))


df2 = df1.pivot_table(index='Date',
                      columns='contract', 
                      values='amount', 
                      fill_value=0, 
                      aggfunc='sum')
```

---

```
print (df2)
contract    1   2   3
Date                 
2022      100   0   0
2023       95  90   0
2024       90  90  50
2025       85  90  50
2026       80  90  50
2027       75  90  50
2028       70  90  50
2029       65  90  50
2030       60  90  50
2031       55  90  50
2032       50  90  50
2033       45  90  50
2034       40  90  50
2035       35  90  50
2036       30  90   0
2037       25  90   0
2038       20  90   0
2039       15  90   0
2040       10  90   0
2041        5  90   0
2042        0  90   0
2043        0  90   0
2044        0  90   0
2045        0  90   0
2046        0  90   0
2047        0  90   0
2048        0  90   0
2049        0  90   0
2050        0  90   0
2051        0  90   0
2052        0  90   0
```

Comment: many thanks! it works perfectly. Just a further question: immagine that  one of these loans has repayment in instalments instead of bullet at maturity so for example the loan_1 starts with 100 and every year the exposure is reduced by 5 (100/20 years). Is there an easy way to account it?

Comment: @NassirBin - How is possible distinguish these loans?

Comment: For example with an additional feature boolean in the first table 'is_instalment'

Comment: @NassirBin - So it means there should be values `100 95 90 85 ... 0` ?

Comment: Yes exactly this